# Duplicate ID in PUT url when editing Restangular model in ui-router custom path

Tags: angular-ui-router, restangular

currently I'm setting up restangular to edit my model. Formerly it was ok when I'm not using custom url to show the form, like

```
http://example.com/admin/clients (I just load the form there).
```

But, then I use ui-router to setup the URL like this

```
http://example.com/admin/clients/{clientId}/edit
```

When I do `model.put()` or `model.save()`, the resulting PUT url is wrong. It become like this

```
PUT http://referral.dev/admin/clients/f2aa1490-5a8f-11e5-b936-b3a54e0c9925/f2aa1490-5a8f-11e5-b936-b3a54e0c9925
```

It should be like this:

```
PUT http://referral.dev/admin/clients/f2aa1490-5a8f-11e5-b936-b3a54e0c9925
```

What I do wrong?

For convenience, here is debug from restangular object:

```
{
    "restangularCollection": false,
    "$object": {
        "id": "f2aa1490-5a8f-11e5-b936-b3a54e0c9925",
        "referrer_id": "f1529d80-5a8f-11e5-8ca1-21124a5fa590",
        "email": "Claudia.Kertzmann@hotmail.com",
        "first_name": "Isabelle",
        "last_name": "Herzog",
        "mobile": "450.357.8579x621",
        "stage": "member",
        "stage_at": "2015-09-09 00:00:00",
        "previous_stages": [
            {
                "stage": "lead",
                "stage_at": "2015-08-30 00:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "total_investment": 190000,
        "email_token": "caf34dddfe00f36b180d459236830934",
        "confirmed": false,
        "unsubscribed": false,
        "transfered_at": null,
        "previous_referrers": [],
        "created_at": "2015-09-14 03:23:20",
        "updated_at": "2015-09-14 03:23:20",
        "referrer": {
            "id": "f1529d80-5a8f-11e5-8ca1-21124a5fa590",
            "email": "Eulalia.Pacocha@Dickens.biz",
            "name": "Esperanza Aufderhar Sr.",
            "mobile": "658.549.0277",
            "role": "referrer",
            "organization_id": "f0577b10-5a8f-11e5-984f-f120de15e3c1",
            "last_login_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "suspended": 0
        },
        "route": "f2aa1490-5a8f-11e5-b936-b3a54e0c9925",
        "reqParams": null,
        "restangularized": true,
        "fromServer": true,
        "parentResource": {
            "route": "admin/clients",
            "parentResource": null
        },
        "restangularCollection": false
    }
}
```

And, here is the restangular object if don't use custom URL (which working):

```
{
    "id": "f2aa1490-5a8f-11e5-b936-b3a54e0c9925",
    "referrer_id": "f1529d80-5a8f-11e5-8ca1-21124a5fa590",
    "email": "Claudia.Kertzmann@hotmail.com",
    "first_name": "Isabelle",
    "last_name": "Herzog",
    "mobile": "450.357.8579x621",
    "stage": "member",
    "stage_at": "2015-09-09 00:00:00",
    "previous_stages": [
        {
            "stage": "lead",
            "stage_at": "2015-08-30 00:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "total_investment": 190000,
    "email_token": "caf34dddfe00f36b180d459236830934",
    "confirmed": false,
    "unsubscribed": false,
    "transfered_at": null,
    "previous_referrers": [],
    "created_at": "2015-09-14 03:23:20",
    "updated_at": "2015-09-14 03:23:20",
    "referrer": {
        "id": "f1529d80-5a8f-11e5-8ca1-21124a5fa590",
        "email": "Eulalia.Pacocha@Dickens.biz",
        "name": "Esperanza Aufderhar Sr.",
        "mobile": "658.549.0277",
        "role": "referrer",
        "organization_id": "f0577b10-5a8f-11e5-984f-f120de15e3c1",
        "last_login_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "suspended": 0
    },
    "route": "admin/clients",
    "reqParams": null,
    "restangularized": true,
    "fromServer": true,
    "parentResource": null,
    "restangularCollection": false
}
```

I've tried manually set `$object.route` to "admin/clients" but the PUT url is still the same.

Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. Formerly I was using:

```
var models = Restangular.all('admin/clients');
```

Then use

```
models.one($stateParams.clientId).get()
```

to get the model.

The correct way, is use `Restangular.one` to load model, eg. like this:

```
vm.model = Restangular.one('admin/clients', $stateParams.clientId).get();
```